# Javascript. Which is the executer?

Tags: javascript

source definition:

-If you return a value the function will stop and send that value back to where it was executed.
--- it stated that "the function will stop and send that value back to where it was executed".<===> My question here is... which is the executioner? ...

code:

```
sayHello(){
return "Hi, are you having a good " + day + "?"
}
```

Comment: You don't have an executioner, or more correctly you never execute the function in that code. On the other hand, you don't have a function either, so there's nothing to execute.

Comment: You mean `var text = sayHello('morning')` where you have  `function sayHello(day){
return "Hi, are you having a good " + day + "?"
}` somewhere. Now the var text will contain _Hi, are you having a good morning?_. The `sayHello('morning')` executes the function

Comment: The function (or a part of code) where you invoke (i.e. call, have a function call `sayHello();` is the executioner. Looks like the MDN article I've linked to in your previous question explains all this pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a function, you must call it. You do not call sayHello() in your example - you only define it.

To call it, you must write:

```
// The function is defined here.
function sayHello(day){
  return "Hi, are you having a good " + day + "?"
}

sayHello("friday"); // <-- The function is executed here. It will return "Hi, are you having a good friday?"
```

You also had two syntax errors in your function. First, you must precede the name of your function with the 'function' keyword. Second, you need to include the 'day' argument in the function's arguments; otherwise, javascript doesn't know what 'day' you're referring to in the return statement.